# Copy file to external storage in android studio with java

Tags: copy

I am using a library to capture photo and I want to save the photo taken in external storage

How can I copy this file in external storage in this?

```
@Override
public void onImageCapture(@NonNull File imageFile) {
```

please guide Me

Comment: Hello Arash. Your question is very unclear and would need some clarification before anyone on this site could help you out proper. Check out ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: ok I am using a library to capture photo and I want to save the photo taken in external storage

Comment: You should improve your questions text so people can help you. It won't help if it's in the comments :)

Comment: thanks i changed it

Comment: You have to be a lot more descriptive than that. What language are you using? What library are you using? What's your code looking like?